# DataContext not updating (newbie question)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an object called 'SelectedDay' I instantiate it like this:

```
Day SelectedDay = new Day(DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001"));
```

In Window_Loaded I set a listBox Datacontext to it:

```
lb_summary.DataContext = SelectedDay;
```

Later on in my app when a user clicks on a day in another ListBox, I pass it the new SelectedDay:

```
public void RefreshSummary(Day _selectedDay)
{
    SelectedDay = _selectedDay;
}
```

Im expecting lb_summary.DataContext to become _selectedDay but nothing happens, SelectedDay is the same as _selectedDay but the lb_summary.DataContext is empty.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:

this is the object structure (they do implement INotifyPropertyChanged, edited to keep breif):

```
public class Day : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DayDate { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Gig> Gigs { get; set; }// gigs booked in a day_cell
}

public class Gig : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Properties of a gig
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now forget all the talk about MVVM and DependencyProperties and the like... we need to get some basics straigt here.

The reason your assignment doesnt work is simple: Your datacontext **doesn't change**, it is SelectedDay that changes. Your Day class is a reference type, so the DataContext when assigned now points to your first SelectedDay object.

However later on you decide to change the assignment of SelectedDay to another Day object. This works, however it does not change the reference the DataContext object has.

Comment: Ahh Ok, Do I need to change the properties of SelectedDay as suggested by Daniel then? I have tried to re-assign the DataContext to _selectedDay but im getting a thread error.

Comment: Do you understand why your first code didn't do what you wanted it to do? Also there are various ways how you can achieve what you want, the Wpf way would surely involve DataBinding of some kind, but since you seem to be pretty novice in Wpf i'd suggest digging up some beginners tutorials on Wpf first. Also, yes if you try to update the UI from a thread that is not the UI thread you will get an exception. Invoke it on the Dispatcher. Again, that is probably stuff you will have to read up on! Good Luck!

Comment: Yeah I understand, Reference Type, many thanks for the pointers UrbanEsc.

Answer (score 1):

As UrbanEsc said, your datacontext does not change. Hence setting the property SelectedDay is not gonna change anything or fire any propertychanges.
To make it work with the code you provided, you should write this:

```
public void RefreshSummary(Day _selectedDay)
{
    lb_summary.DataContext = _selectedDay;
}
```

but as others pointed out, it would be better to set your DataContext to an object, and bind the listbox to a property of that object.

Comment: I get what UrbanEsc is saying, I tried what you suggested Roel but as im using background workers, im getting a thread error, im thinking I should change the properties of SelectedDay to those of _selectedDay. I will also look at setting my DataContext to an object but will I still get thread errors? Sorry if its obvious, still learning

Comment: If you are in code-behind, you can use `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(d => lb_summary.DataContext = d), _selectedDay);` This will make sure this is executed on the UI-thread. Edit: If you use `DataContext` and `Binding` then the `InotifyPropertyChanged` event handling by WPF will handle the threading issues itself.

Comment: I'd suggest not doing the above but instead reading up a bit on Wpf concepts and rethinking your current implementation instead. Edit: Also it is wrong that "the event handling by wpf" will "handle threading issues". It is the dispatcher that will queue up incoming "messages" and than execute it on its thread, which is the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't bind to a value. You change the properties and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are to use `Binding`? with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and notify about property changed via `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MVVM design pattern](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx). Here, you would create a view model type which contains the `SelectedDay` property and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model. In the setter for your `SelectedDay` property, you would invoke the `PropertyChanged` event. You would then set the DataContext of your view to an instance of your view model.

Answer (score 0):

If SelectedDay is not part of your ViewModel and might be a property of your control itself (for instance, a datepicker might have a SelectedDay property), consider making SelectedDay a DependencyProperty on your control, so it will handle the notification to the UI:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDay", typeof(Day), typeof(type_of_yourcontrol for instance DatePicker?));

public Day SelectedDay
{
     get { return (Day)GetValue(SelectedDayProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SelectedDayProperty, value); }
}
```